# check answers on jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is there a way to make worksheets with jupyter notebooks such that in a field the answer/code of the user is compared to a previously defined solution and a feedback (e.g. if the values of a result are the same in both codes or maybe even if in some sense the codes fit semantically) is reported to the user?
A kernel with python 3 would be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that being done in https://www.kaggle.com/learn, where you can see it in action.

There is some documentation in https://github.com/Kaggle/learntools/tree/master/learntools/core